# Mysql Order by two columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
id     |date        |publisher
1       2014-11-07   100
2       2014-11-07   0
3       2014-11-07   100
4       2014-11-06   0
5       2014-11-06   100
6       2014-11-05   100
7       2014-11-05   0
8       2014-11-05   0
9       2014-11-05   100
```

I am trying to get a result like this :

```
1       2014-11-07   100
3       2014-11-07   100
2       2014-11-07   0
4       2014-11-06   100   
5       2014-11-06   0
6       2014-11-05   100
9       2014-11-05   100
8       2014-11-05   0
7       2014-11-05   100
```

SO I am trying to sort the data in table by publish date and allways keep the publisher values on top for each day I got this so far:

```
select * from articles 
order by publisher DESC, date DESC
```

I get this result:

```
1       2014-11-07   100
3       2014-11-07   100
5       2014-11-06   100
6       2014-11-05   100
9       2014-11-05   100
2       2014-11-07   0
4       2014-11-06   0
7       2014-11-05   0
8       2014-11-05   0
```

Which is wrong....

Comment: flip your `ORDER BY` to `ORDER BY date DESC, publisher DESC`

Comment: In the result you like to get, The date 05 has 100 in the last row...??? But your need is like Desc by date then Desc by value right? If it so ..? Then use orders as recommended by @cmorrissey... Otherwise clarify your need

Comment: yep I tried the order in both ways has the same result.... :o

Answer (score 1):

You must invert the order of order by field, like this:

```
select * from articles 
order by date DESC, publisher DESC
```

The ORDER BY clause take care about order of field. In this query we tell: order by date in desc order and if two or more dates are equals, apply a further order on publisher in desc order.

**EDIT**
As I promised, go to [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce5669/1/0)

Comment: Hey thex for help but this does nto work it has the same effect

Comment: Dear, not possible. Sorry but Sql Fiddle today is down, when Sql fiddle goes up I create your result set with my query.